# How does a dynamic library's references to a global variable get translated once in the running app?

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

If a dynamic library exports the address to a global variable defined within the library, how are accesses to that variable translated during dynamic linking so that a running application can interact with it?

Comment: *Compiling* does the same thing as always - it dumps its symbol table into the object code, translating variable names into offsets. Fixing up the address so that an already running process can read/write it is the job of the *dynamic linker* or *loader*.

Comment: Do you mean a global variable? In C, which you tagged your question with, static variables have internal linkage - they're not visible outside the translation unit, much less outside a dynamic library.

Comment: @KilianFoth true. I will edit my question.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes, I did mean to say global, thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean: "If a dynamic library exports the address *of* a global variable defined within the library"? That changes the meaning of the question!

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific (and *very* different on Linux and on Windows; read Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book).

For Linux, a good explanation happens in Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

In general, the access to such a global variable may involve some indirection. Read about the [Global Offset Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table).